# usb multicardreader detected, but device not shown/available, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, ubuntu-12.04, card-reader

I have problems with my usb cardreader in Linux Ubuntu 12.04 . I think the device is detected by the operating system, but not shown in category devices and therefore not available.

I have checked the following commands:

cardreader not connected:

```
USER@USER-VPCEA25EC:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6409 Microdia Webcam

USER@USER-VPCEA25EC:~$ mount
/dev/sda8 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/USER/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=USER)
/dev/sda2 on /media/System Reserved type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /media/4CA4D15EA4D14B5A type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5 on /media/327CD6DA7CD69845 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda6 on /media/361ADB7E1ADB3997 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

cardreader with micro-sd card connected:

```
USER@USER-VPCEA25EC:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6409 Microdia Webcam
Bus 002 Device 021: ID 14cd:125c Super Top

USER@USER-VPCEA25EC:~$ mount
/dev/sda8 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/USER/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=USER)
/dev/sda2 on /media/System Reserved type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /media/4CA4D15EA4D14B5A type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5 on /media/327CD6DA7CD69845 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda6 on /media/361ADB7E1ADB3997 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)

sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for USER:
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x77f5110c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    27928575    13963264   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    27928576    28133375      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        28133376   364473007   168169816    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       364478462   625139711   130330625    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       364478464   433210367    34365952    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       501944320   625139711    61597696    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       497909760   501934079     2012160   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8       433211392   497901567    32345088   83  Linux

dmesg [just the last lines of the output!]
[11195.873212] usb 2-1.2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[11195.873217] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[11195.873222] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 125C20100726
[11195.873808] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[11195.874002] scsi11 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[11196.872337] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device        PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[11196.872819] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[11196.878942] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[11216.680055] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 15
[11248.663928] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
[11248.903959] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[11248.997457] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=125c
[11248.997467] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[11248.997473] usb 2-1.2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[11248.997478] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[11248.997482] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 125C20100726
[11248.998059] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[11248.998772] scsi12 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[11249.996821] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device        PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[11249.997373] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[11250.001521] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[11304.368082] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 17
[11349.255534] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[11349.495569] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
[11349.589079] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=125c
[11349.589088] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[11349.589094] usb 2-1.2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[11349.589099] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[11349.589104] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 125C20100726
[11349.589680] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[11349.589873] scsi13 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[11350.588456] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device        PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[11350.589023] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[11350.591868] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[11549.106742] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 19
[11661.900041] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 20 using ehci-pci
[11662.140080] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 21 using ehci-pci
[11662.233579] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=125c
[11662.233588] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[11662.233594] usb 2-1.2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[11662.233599] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[11662.233604] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 125C20100726
[11662.234192] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[11662.234388] scsi14 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[11663.232944] scsi 14:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device        PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[11663.235492] sd 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[11663.238969] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[12303.061357] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
[12303.999994] wlan0: authenticate with a2:05:43:f3:75:03
[12304.022878] wlan0: send auth to a2:05:43:f3:75:03 (try 1/3)
[12304.259518] wlan0: send auth to a2:05:43:f3:75:03 (try 2/3)
[12304.363523] wlan0: send auth to a2:05:43:f3:75:03 (try 3/3)
[12304.377861] wlan0: authenticated
[12304.379494] wlan0: associate with a2:05:43:f3:75:03 (try 1/3)
[12304.400489] wlan0: RX AssocResp from a2:05:43:f3:75:03 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[12304.400569] wlan0: associated
[16693.996812] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 21
[16712.351561] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 22 using ehci-pci
[16712.591595] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 23 using ehci-pci
[16712.685133] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=125c
[16712.685143] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[16712.685150] usb 2-1.2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[16712.685155] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[16712.685159] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 125C20100726
[16712.686294] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[16712.686481] scsi15 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[16713.684589] scsi 15:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device        PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[16713.685137] sd 15:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[16713.691113] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[17520.033230] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 23
[17622.276736] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 24 using ehci-pci
[17622.372987] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2510
[17622.372997] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[17622.373003] usb 2-1.2: Product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[17622.373008] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: PIXART
[17622.377104] input: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/input/input12
[17622.377365] hid-generic 0003:093A:2510.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[18029.260300] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 24
[18030.972120] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 25 using ehci-pci
[18031.212164] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 26 using ehci-pci
[18031.305422] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=125c
[18031.305432] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[18031.305438] usb 2-1.2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[18031.305443] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[18031.305448] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 125C20100726
[18031.306025] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[18031.306206] scsi16 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[18032.305030] scsi 16:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device        PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[18032.305584] sd 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[18032.309586] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[18038.267625] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 26
[18043.434048] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 27 using ehci-pci
[18043.674116] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 28 using ehci-pci
[18043.767622] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=125c
[18043.767632] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[18043.767638] usb 2-1.2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[18043.767643] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[18043.767648] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 125C20100726
[18043.768227] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[18043.768422] scsi17 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[18044.766927] scsi 17:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device        PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[18044.767441] sd 17:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[18044.773377] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[18877.756516] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 28
[18883.252261] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 29 using ehci-pci
[18883.348439] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2510
[18883.348449] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[18883.348455] usb 2-1.2: Product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[18883.348459] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: PIXART
[18883.352456] input: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/input/input13
[18883.352731] hid-generic 0003:093A:2510.0003: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[32313.790925] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 29
[32322.725326] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 30 using ehci-pci
[32322.965329] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
[32323.058861] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=125c
[32323.058870] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[32323.058876] usb 2-1.2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[32323.058881] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[32323.058886] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 125C20100726
[32323.059323] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[32323.059471] scsi18 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[32324.058168] scsi 18:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device        PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[32324.058941] sd 18:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[32324.064521] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

How can I fix this problem?

greetings

Answer (score 2):

The Card Reader does work on Ubuntu 12.04 but the OS doesn't seem to find the card when it is inserted. It appears you have 2 options in the short term :

A. Reboot with the sdcard in the slot ;-)

B. Do a pci re-scan (execute the following as root)

```
sudo su -l

echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

The bug with the workaround is listed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/995743)

OR:

On the terminal type `sudo blkid` before inserting the device, this will print all the block devices currently on your system. Now insert the device and type sudo blkid again. Now you will see that the new device has been added (either as `/dev/sdbx` or as `/dev/sdcx` or as /dev/sddx, where x>=1).

Now go to the terminal again and type `sudo mount /dev/sdxx /dir/to/be/mounted/` where xx are the last 2 letters of the device that you just detected.

Now, the files will be accessible at the `/dir/to/be/mounted`. Also make note that you have use sudo to copy files into the directory.

And before you remove the device, unmount it using `sudo umount /dev/sdxx`

Comment: @G Koe : I tried all solution methods, but unfortunately nothing did solve the problem. When I tried solution 3: `sudo blkid` did not show a new device after I inserted the cardreader including micro sd card. thx anyway for the help :).

Comment: I've had the same behaviour.  I plugged in and unplugged my usb card reader several times, with it working fine, then it just stopped recognising the card.  I can see it in lspci and lsusb and even in dmesg, but not in blkid or /proc/partitions